# How to correctly lemmatize the text column in R?

Tags: data-science-model, nlp

I'm working on a project in Natural Language Processing. I have a data frame that has a text column. I have to lemmatize that text column. I'm using lemmatize_strings() function in R. However, there's one case where word 'wound' in one of the text is being lemmatized to 'wind' which is not correct. Can anybody tell me what can be done to correct this ?

Comment: could you add the snippet of the exact error?

Comment: @SoumyaKundu, I have original text as - 'Wound in the finger'. After removing stopwords and lemmatizing it the result is 'wind finger'